# SVN fix branching from subfolder to trunk

Tags: svn, version-control, branching-and-merging

When creating my branch in svn, I branched from a subfolder of trunk by mistake and not the trunk itself.
I realised my mistake too late, and I have made several commits on that branch and worked for some time on it.

Now, I want to merge updates from the main trunk, and realised my mistake, and of course it causes issues.
Is there a way to fix it easily and keep the commit history? Like "rebase" (not sure this is the correct term) the branch from the subfolder to the main trunk.
Or do I have to create a new branch and copy the modifications to it by hand?

Thanks.

Comment: You can create a new branch from trunk, and perform a merge from your old branch to the corresponding subfolder in the new branch. Then forget your old branch and enjoy the new branch !